# Is there a way to get stdout from a process to display on tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, subprocess, stdout, openvpn

So what I am trying to do is take the output from OpenVPN and display as part of a GUI I am writing in Python/TKinter.

Is there a way to communicate between the process and the GUI, like with text being moved between the two processes?

I am using "subprocess" to call OpenVPN, but after that all of the text is displayed in the terminal emulator.

I have already played around with popen, and read the docs but I can't find any decent examples.

Here is some sample code of the command being called:

`subprocess.run(['sudo', '/usr/sbin/openvpn', "--config", self.filePath])`

Comment: you have to catch `stdout` in subprocess, get text and put it in Label or Text.

Comment: does `/usr/sbin/openvpn` need interaction ? If you have to get only displayed text then you can use `text  = subprocess.check_output(...)`.

Comment: @furas What do you mean by catch? Would I add a extra argument to display stdout in a certain object (like a label?)

Comment: Seems like there exists a library [openpyn](https://pypi.org/project/openpyn/) to manage openvpn connection in python. Maybe that's simpler to use that to make your GUI rather than catching subprocess output.

Comment: @j_4321 I'll give that a look cheers

Comment: `subprocess.run(command, .., stdout=subprocess.PIPE)` but easier is to `text = subprocess.check_output(command)`, and `label["text"] = text` - if you don't run interactive command which need text from user.

Comment: here is example which [runs ping and display in tkinter's Label](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/blob/master/tkinter/subprocess/example-1.py)

Comment: Because the program may need sudo, and also credential input from the user, is there a way to detect when the program wants input an to prompt the user graphically to provide it? Sorry for all these questions.

Comment: You may want to check the `sh` module, a higher level wrapper around `subprocess`.